# Write list of elements to csv file with seprated by space

Tags: python-3.x, list, csv, text, delimiter

I have pdf file and extracting table fro it. Ca not share data and so createdone sample of how I want things to be wroked

I have a list
l = [a,bd,c f,e]

I want csv file like

```
col1  col2  
 a
 bd
 c     f
 e
```

Comment: Why should `f` go to `col2` and all others to `col1`?

Comment: What's the logic here ?

Comment: I am extracting table from pdf and I can not share that but I am getting list of list like above containg text. I can make table from that based on above logic so this question has been posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option I found is convert list into dataframe

df = pd.DataFrame(l)

then split it

df[0].str.split(" ", n = 1, expand = True)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
import csv

myheaders = ['col1', 'col2']
mydata = [['a'],['bd'],['c', 'f'],['e']]

with open('test.csv', 'w') as target:
  writer = csv.writer(target, delimiter=' ')
  writer.writerow(myheaders)
  writer.writerows(mydata)
```

Comment: How do you make [a,bd,c f,e] to [[['a'],['bd'],['c', 'f'],['e']]]